# Puppeteer - Text Keyboard Input won't work on dropdown popup

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js, puppeteer, ui-automation

I'm using Puppeteer and Mocha library for E2E UI Test, and I'm having trouble with text input.

Here are the screenshots of the elements I'm trying to access:
[Rename Dropdown Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP42H.png)
[Renaming Text Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VohqU.png)

After clicking the 'Rename Dropdown' and the keboard focus is automatically on the input area, 'page.type()' fuction won't work. (Manual keyboard input & Pressing Enter works normally)

Not sure if it's an issue regarding the breakdow>popup structure, or if it's puppeteer's own defect.

```
it(`UT - ${++i} : LNB - Rename Folder`, async function () {    
    await util.click(DP.LNB_newFolder_svg_xp);  // opens up the rename text popup
    await this.timeout(5000);
    // await LP.setId(DP.LNB_newFolder_palceholder_xp, "Created New Folder");
    // await util.click(XP.LNB_newFolder_palceholder_xp);  // not neccessary to click placeholder
    await page.type("test comment");  // where it won't type
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");  // neither does it press Enter
 });
```